# multiple arrays in a listview

Tags: android

For my listview, I want to be able to display multiple textviews within it, with each textview displaying the items of a specific array associated with it. Right now is what I have:

```
public class GreatestHits extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, Array1));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
          String text = (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
}

    });

}
 static final String[] Array1 = new String[] {"Item1", "Item2"};
 static final String[] Array2 = new String[] {"Item1", "Item2"};
static final String[] Array3 = new String[] {"Item1", "Item2"};
```

and the xml for R.layout.list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:id= "@+id/textView1" 
>

</TextView>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" 
android:id= "@+id/textView2" 
>
</TextView>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" 
android:id= "@+id/textView3" 
>
</TextView>
```

How would I put array 2 and array 3 into the code so it can be displayed in the textviews of listview lv?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. You want each cell in the listview to have three textview's one from each array... is that correct?

Comment: extend the arrayadapter and implement th function getView as you wish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArrayAdapter can only display data from one array in one textview. You will have to provide this functionality yourself by extending BaseAdapter yourself. I can't compile android code at the moment, so the following code is untested... but it should at least give you an indication of what you can do.

```
public class TripleArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private String[] array1, array2, array3;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  public TripleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] a1, String[] a2, String[]a3) {
    array1 = a1;
    array2 = a2;
    array3 = a3;
    inflater = 
        (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return array1.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View currentView = convertView;

    if(currentView==null) {
      currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView tView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tView.setText(array1[position]);

    tView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tView.setText(array2[position]);

    tView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tView.setText(array3[position]);

    return currentView;
  }
}
```

Then, to use this adapter as your ListActivity's adapter, you would just say

```
setListAdapter(new TripleArrayAdapter(this, Array1, Array2, Array3));
```